# IE8 hack .htc hack is working on local but not on server

Tags: ie8-compatibility-mode, background-size

I am using hack for IE8 to get max width. The script is working perfectly fine on local but when I upload it to server, its not working for some reason. Here is the link

The hack is

```
ms-behavior: url('/css/backgroundsize.min.htc');
```

I want to make this script work, as it's perect on local, I tried many others and it had conflict with other scripts already running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIG Problem with a simple solution, I had to add this line to my .htaccess file at root directory location

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

and it started working like anything...